# Importing observer from mobx-react causes "Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, mobx, browserify-rails

I'm using [rails-browserify](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) with my rails project to compile a reactJS application.

My node package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.1.1",
    "mobx": "^2.4.2",
    "mobx-react": "^3.5.4",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

However, whenever I `import { observer } from 'mobx-react'`,
I get an

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

This doesn't happen for any other libraries that I import. `react`, `mobx`, `react-dom` all import fine. Let me know if you need any other details. Any help is appreciated. I'm really stumped here.

The module in question looks like so. I have not used mobx-react in the component yet, only imported it. It's the import { observer } line that triggers the error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

export default class OnboardingHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...}
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the observer on the React component? How are you importing React?

Comment: Updated the original post. They're all imported through npm and the observer hasn't been implemented yet, only imported. Even if I add the @observer decorator, the issues still persists.

Comment: So if you just remove the import statement from mobx-react, it works? That's odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I didn't fix the issue, but I figured out a workaround for now.

I moved the observer import into a two step method and babelify seems to like that better. I changed

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
```

to

```
import mobxReact from 'mobx-react';
const { observer } = mobxReact;
```

Everything seems to work fine now. The issue seems to lie with babelify and how it's translating the import with the library.

Comment: If this is still an issue, feel free to open an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react